# Calling ASP.NET page from a JS and sending Response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, webforms

I have a JS script:

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: ServiceAddress + "/Service.aspx?action=LoadRandomImagePath&userID=" + USER_ID,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.LoadRandomImagePathResult.ID != 0) {
        //something
        }
```

When Service.aspx is called:

```
Response.Write(svc.LoadRandomImagePath(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["userID"])));
```

svc.LoadRandomImagePath returns JSON and writes it to Response.

My problem is following.
Result on JS side is a full code of Service.aspx:

```
{JSON HERE}  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <head><title> </title></head> <body> <form method="post" action="Service.aspx?action=LoadRandomImagePath&amp;userID=18" id="form1"> <div class="aspNetHidden"> <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwULLTE2MTY2ODcyMjlkZLyq7A39QtHu0Ngft6E/6ZwTABk29noGDsoP6FKK6UIo" /> </div> <div> </div> </form> </body> </html>
```

but what I want is only JSON response, without code of the page. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried specifying the return data type as a JSON in your initial request?

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: ServiceAddress + "/Service.aspx?action=LoadRandomImagePath&userID=" + USER_ID,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.LoadRandomImagePathResult.ID != 0) {
        //something
 }
```

Additionally you will want to clear anything written already and change the data type for the JSON page:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Response.Write(svc.LoadRandomImagePath(int.Parse(Request.QueryString["userID"])));
Response.End();
```